# How to solve app icon grey in notifications

Tags: flutter

I have an image (.png) as an icon of my app, but it is grey when it shows in the notification. how can I solve this? I want my colorful image as an icon. Thanks!

I understand a small notification icon in the status bar is impossible (photo_2) but could I change to a color icon when the notification is expanded? (photo_1)

[image: photo_1]

[image: photo_2]

Comment: What Icon exactly are you speaking of? A screenshot might come handy here.

Comment: But for instance android doesn't support colored icons in the status bar. Read the design guidelines for the platform you are developing for

Comment: In this [repository here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit) you can create notification tray icons

Answer (score 2):

The icon to be used for notifications must be white-colored and with transparent background else it will show a grey-colored box.

Comment: White colored means a white image? but if the notification backgroud color is white, how can it will be visible?

Comment: try to make it transparent since it will be white by deafult

Answer (score 1):

Before starting, make sure your icon or image has a transparent background. The solution will seem like it's not working if your image background has a color. (as @Aia Ashraf answer)

Create your mipmap notification icon. You can do this easily using [Roman's Notification Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) - Click on "Notification Icon Generator"

And also you can try [appicon.co](https://www.appicon.co/)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have your vibrant icon image prepared.
For your personalized notification, make a new XML layout file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).